# How do you define custom behaviours for the Android phone's volume buttons using Adobe AIR (ActionScript 3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, keylistener

For buttons like the MENU or BACK button you can just add a listener for KeyboardEvent and check if the event keyCode is Keyboard.BACK or Keyboard.MENU.

However I don't see anything for knowing if the phone's volume buttons were pressed.

Is there a way to listen for volume up and volume down keyUp/keyDown events in AIR (ActionScript 3)?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There isn't any support for detecting the volume buttons. (In AIR 3, you can write a native extension to access native features that aren't otherwise supported.)